# Does LPPL allow package development with pull requests etc.?

Tags: package-writing, licensing

Many packages are nowadays developed on github or similar platforms and if I want to contribute a bugfix to some package (of which I'm not the author), my usual workflow is to fork the repo, develop the bugfix, make a pull request and then I have to wait until the package author accepts my fix.

I'm wondering if my workflow is in conflict with the [LPPL](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX_Project_Public_License) (LaTeX Project Public License), because in the time between developing the fix until the author accepts my pull request, the code is changed without changing the filename.

Is there some other strategy I could use, which would respect LPPL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The requirement to change the file name was altered several years ago; what is needed now is a prominent notice on any *distribution*. Code contained *in a version control system* has the notice *in that system itself*, and thus does not need to be modified to indicate a change. That applies equally to for example a Subversion client-server arrangement as to a Git distributed set up, which includes GitHub.

The point at which a 'notice' is required is when something leaves version control, for example to go to CTAN or on a webpage as a direct upload.

Comment: I can see and would have argued myself that Sections 6(b) ["details of changes"] and 6(d) ["unmodified version"] are sort of covered by version control systems. But 6(a) seems a bit more tricky, since as I understand it would involve a change of the `\ProvidesPackage` line so that TeX "knows" the file is different when it reads it...

Comment: @moewe One would need real legal opinion to be sure, but I'd hope the fact that Frank _etc._ are happy should reassure everyone. After all, they wrote the text in the first place ...

Comment: @moewe I think unless there is a real reason, no-one fancies having a new version of the license ... (I _intensely_ dislike 'author-maintained', but it's there.)

Comment: I can imagine that only very few people (or even no one) would be excited about a new version of the license. And I can imagine that people who are very protective about their packages might not even want to have an exception for version control systems (and would probably also not like to see 'author-maintained' go). But I'm not sure that the everyday practice and statements of intent of the LaTeX team towards the license will help me in court should it come to that, but I'm hopeful that it won't come to that.